# choice primary images in microdata schema.org

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I know 'primaryImageOfPage' is a property of WebPage.
But 'primaryImageOfPage' isn't a property of Article.

For this code:

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/webpage">
<head>
<meta itemprop="name" content="webpage"/>
</head>

<body>

    <p itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
       <img src"example1.png" itemprop="image"/>
       <img src"example2.png" itemprop="image"/>
       <img src"example3.png" itemprop="image"/>
       <img src"example4.png" itemprop="image"/>
    </p>

</body>

</html>
```

How can I choice Primaery picture for Article?
Dose Article inherits from Webpage? 
FOr example:

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/webpage">
<head>
<meta itemprop="name" content="webpage"/>
</head>

<body>

    <p itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
       <img src"example1.png" itemprop="primaryImageOfPage"/>
       <img src"example2.png" itemprop="image"/>
       <img src"example3.png" itemprop="image"/>
       <img src"example4.png" itemprop="image"/>
    </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Article inherit from WebPage?

No. You can’t use [`primaryImageOfPage`](http://schema.org/primaryImageOfPage) for Article.

While it makes sense to specify the main content/image of a WebPage, would it also make sense to specify this for an Article? I’d say that an Article should only contain *main* content/images in the first place.

If there is an image the whole Article is about, you could use the [`about` property](http://schema.org/about). Example: interpretation of a painting. If this image is from a different source, you could use the [`citation` property](http://schema.org/citation) in addition.

For images being part of the Article, there is the [`associatedMedia` property](http://schema.org/associatedMedia). While its description is somewhat confusing, it got [discussed](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2012Feb/thread.html#msg66) that this property could be used for linking images (or other media) that belong to or are part of the Article (currently, it has the synonym [`encoding`](http://schema.org/encoding), which they planned to remove; I don’t know why that did not happen yet).

Note that I wouldn’t use the [`image` property](http://schema.org/image) for all images that are part of the Article. I think this property should only be used for images of the Article itself, i.e., images representing this whole Article. This could be a screenshot of the Article, a thumbnail, maybe a lead picture.

So, you could use `associatedMedia` for the main image(s) and no property for secondary images:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <span itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <img itemprop="contentUrl" src"main-image.png" alt="…" />
  </span>
  <img src"secondary-image-1.png" alt="…" />
  <img src"secondary-image-2.png" alt="…" />
  <img src"secondary-image-3.png" alt="…" />
</article>
```

Comment: Hi Unin and thanks for your answer But I confused a little. Why do you use 'associatedMedia' instead 'image'? and why leave other images?(because we can tel to search engine about name and describtion of those images)

Comment: @user3307827: `image` is for an image **of** the whole Article (i.e., representing it, or being an alternative representation). `associatedMedia` is for an image that is **part of** the Article. --- If you want to describe *all* images, you could of course use `associatedMedia` for all of them (but I thought you only want to do this for main (= important) images).